# Top n outliers in ResultWriter

Tags: data-mining, outliers, elki

I am dealing with high dimensional and large dataset, so i need to get just Top N outliers from  output of `ResultWriter`.
There is some option in elki to get just the top N outliers from this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResultWriter` is some of the oldest code in ELKI, and needs to be rewritten. It's rather generic - it tries to figure out how to best serialize output as text.

If you want some specific format, or a specific subset, the proper way is to write your own `ResultHandler`. There is a [tutorial for writing a `ResultHandler`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/ResultHandler).

If you want to find the input coordinates in the result,

```
Database db = ResultUtil.findDatabase(baseResult);
Relation<NumberVector> rel = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.NUMBER_VECTOR_VARIABLE_LENGTH);
```

will return the first relation containing numeric vectors.

To iterate over the objects sorted by their outlier score, use:

```
OrderingResult order = outlierResult.getOrdering();
DBIDs ids = order.order(order.getDBIDs());
for (DBIDIter it = ids.iter(); it.valid(); it.advance()) {
  // Output as desired.
}
```

Comment: Hi Erich, thank you for your answer. I've implemented but in line `DBIDs ids = order.order(order.getDBIDs());` i get a error. So i've changed to `DBIDs ids = order.getDBIDs();` This way run but it is ordering by ids, not by scores. Does it exist order method by scores? I'm looking for in javadoc but i can't find.

Comment: i got it.
i've changed to `DBIDs ids = order.iter(order.getDBIDs());`. So, the result was ordering by scores. thanks a lot.